# Why is assertDictEqual needed if dicts can be compared by `==`?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, dictionary

To be honest I have always used `assertDictEqual`, because sometime when I didn't use it I got information, that equal dicts are not the same.

But... I know that dicts can be compared by `==` operator:

```
>>> {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': [1,2]} == {'b':2, 'a':1, 'c': [1,2]}
True
```

Where I actually may need `assertDictEqual`?

Comment: Because `unittest` can then give you more information about exactly *how* they differed, and give you useful feedback as opposed to a simple `AssertionError`. If you use e.g. `py.test`, you can just use the regular `assert` and it works out the appropriate error reports by introspection.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Basically, it allows `unittest` to give you more information about *why* the test failed ([*"diagnostics"*](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/figures/feedback-on-diagnostics.svg), to use the language from "Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests" by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce). Compare these two tests:

```
import unittest


class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase):

    D1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2]}
    D2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1]}

    def test_not_so_useful(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.D1 == self.D2)

    def test_useful(self):
        self.assertDictEqual(self.D1, self.D2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And their outputs:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_not_so_useful (__main__.DemoTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 10, in test_not_so_useful
    self.assertTrue(self.D1 == self.D2)
AssertionError: False is not true
```

vs.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_useful (__main__.DemoTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line 13, in test_useful
    self.assertDictEqual(self.D1, self.D2)
AssertionError: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2]} != {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1]}
- {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1, 2]}
?                         ---

+ {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1]}
```

In the latter, you can see exactly what the difference was, you don't have to work it out yourself. Note that you can just use the standard `assertEqual` instead of `assertDictEqual`, with the same result; per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#type-specific-methods)

> ...it’s usually not necessary to invoke these methods directly.

Comment: I came across this while doing code reviews and I noticed that the accepted answer is no longer true. As of `python 2.7.15`

`assertEqual` behaves the same as `assertDictEqual` when the inputs are dictionaries. Which ever method I used, I got the same detailed output.

Comment: @ivange94 I did say that explicitly in the answer. The comparison here was to `assert a == b`.

Comment: Oh my bad. @johrsharpe. I didn't read the question properly. In my mind the question was `why use assertDictEqual when assertEqual can compare dictionaries`

Comment: Does assert dict equal consider the order of keys or not?

Comment: @variable it's just a wrapper around a simple equality comparison: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/unittest/case.py#L1205

Comment: Just wanted to know how dict equality works - is it independent of key order?

Comment: @variable dictionaries *aren't ordered data structures*; even in recent versions of Python where insertion order is guaranteed to be retained, `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} == {'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}`. You can easily try this yourself.

Answer (score 9):

This is part of a broader question:

Why does `unittest` have all the special asserts at all?

The answer is that the primary job of the `UnitTest` `assert*` methods is to give you meaningful output when a test fails. Take a look at the `unittest` module code -- that really is mostly what they do (only what they do?)

Given that Python is a dynamic language with easy introspection, why bother will all that? And the answer is "because `unittest` was ported from the Java `junit` package, and that's how they did it in Java" (and probably had to, given how much harder or impossible it is to introspect at run time).

So my recommendation: unless you are writing tests for the standard library, don't use unittest at all -- all it does is get in the way. I use `pytest`. `nose` may be a good option as well. It make it quicker and easier to write tests, and you get excellent reporting when you get errors.

It also includes lots of nifty features for parameterized testing, fixtures, test configuration, mocking, etc...

If you are on a project that already uses `unittest` -- you still can run your tests with `pytest`, and get many of its advantages.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in the context of unit testing. The `assertDictEqual` method will not only compare the `dict`s and evaluate to `True` or `False` but can give you additional information, such as the exact differences between the two `dict`s.

Moreover, in a good IDE the unit tests will integrate nicely. You can just add a `TestCase`, use `assertDictEqual` and the IDE will find and run the test for you. The output is then displayed in an easy to read format. This can save you a lot of boilerplate code.

I would be very interested in a case where two equal `dict`s are not equal when compared with `==`.

Comment: Since dict is an unordered structure, assertDictEqual does not consider order of items. Do you know if this concept has changed given that python 3.7 onwards dict is ordered (maintains insertion order)?

Comment: @variable still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414326/why-is-assertdictequal-needed-if-dicts-can-be-compared-by/34414467#comment104083120_34414463