# Python Unittest Allow Multiple Possible Return Values

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm writing a unittest that will be run on my class's code. For one of the functions they must write, there are two possible return values that they could return and either one is okay for my purposes.

I've been using

```
actual = my_function_call(arg1, arg2)
self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

But this doesn't work for accepting one of two valid return values, so I've changed it to:

```
actual = my_function_call(arg1, arg2)
self.assertEqual(actual == expected1 or actual == expected2, True)
```

Is there a way to do this that isn't as hacky?

Comment: Use: `self.assertTrue(actual == expected1 or actual == expected2)`

Comment: I've found it, thanks everyone! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506299/how-to-assert-equality-for-one-of-multiple-outcomes-on-python3-unittest

Comment: @jarmod note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035906/python-unittest-allow-multiple-possible-return-values/71035960#comment125575101_71035960, your suggestion has a similar problem. It's fine when the test passes, but if it ever _fails_ it's not particularly helpful in figuring out what the problem was. (Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414463/3001761)

Comment: @jonrsharpe agreed, much better. Wasn't aware of assertIn until I read the docs earlier, at which point I was beyond the 5 minute window to edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists [`assertIn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn) test, which you could use in this case as follows

```
self.assertIn(actual,[expected1,expected2])
```

it does check if `actual` is present in list holding `expected1`,`expected2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `assertTrue` and `in`

```py
self.assertTrue(actual in (expected1, expected2))
```

Comment: There's also [`assertIn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn), which gives **substantially** better [diagnostics](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/figures/feedback-on-diagnostics.svg) on failure than `assertTrue` (_"<member> not found in <container>"_ vs. _"False is not true"_). `assertTrue` is rarely the best expectation (unless you're actually testing a function returning a boolean), as it flattens the feedback down to a binary outcome.